# Only accept form input for order number using letters starting in DU-

Tags: html, regex, forms, validation

I have an HTML form and need to accept orders numbers only with a specific prefix `DU-`

I am getting a prompt if a random number is entered but also if DU- is used too.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[^DU-]" title="Order numbers start with DU-" name="orders" class="form2" id="order-ref" placeholder="Please add your order ref"
required>
```

What is the correct regex to only allow certain order numbers with the prefix `DU-`

Comment: `pattern="DU-\d+"` will allow `DU-` followed with 1+ digits.

Comment: Do you mean you only want to require `DU-` at the start? Then use `pattern="DU-.*"`. Please clarify the *only allow certain order numbers* part.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, All order numbers must start with ```DU-```, so DU-45 and DU-lv will all go through fine but any other prefix TU- or DU55 should be rejected. Do I need the hat at the beginning of the pattern? ```pattern="[^DU-.*]"``` - At the moment they are passing through

Comment: So after `DU-` there can be any alphanumeric? Use `pattern="DU-[a-zA-Z0-9]+"` then. BTW, I do not include `^` and `[]` in my `pattern` expression on purpose. DO NOT add them.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have done it. If I wanted to accept lowercase as well eg ```wc-54543``` how would I add that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to only pass strings that start with `DU-` and then contain alphanumeric chars.

Use

```
pattern="DU-[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
```

It [will be translated](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) into `^(?:DU-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` pattern and will match

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:DU-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)` - `DU-` and then 1 or more ASCII letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

If you want to make the pattern more lenient, lax, you may match any one or more non-whitespace chars after `DU-`:

```
pattern="DU-\S+"
```

Or, if you plan to match anything after `DU-`, use

```
pattern="DU-.*"
```

where `.*` matches any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.